# First steps in iOS application development?

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, xcode, variables

Ok, its one of those questions where the guy asking is completely lost...

I want to develop for iOS but the Objective-C code looks alien to me. I am used to using PHP in the procedural style.

I want to be able to set a variable and then have that variable echoed out on the iOS simulator (no buttons to press, just the variable to echo).

How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You would buy a book for newbie Objective-C developers. Stackoverflow is not your personal lecturer

Comment: @zerks im a total newbie and I don't want to learn from manuals, I learned php like this, I mean where do i start?? I need some online resource

Comment: how about http://google.com "objective-c tutorial". "I don't want to learn from manuals" --- omg. And thanks god you're not surgeon.

Comment: Read the book here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_5_Development_Essentials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa and Objective-C resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo in console: AppDelegate.m in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

```
NSString *string = @"Hello World";
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

To create new label: ViewController.m in the viewDidLoad method

```
NSString *string = @"Hello World";

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 25)];
label.text = string;
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: in which file? the main file or the head file?

Comment: and umm where in the file...

Comment: AppDelegate.m in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

Comment: slight problem, it doesnt put anything onto the screen... a terminal-like thing pops up at the bottom with `hello wolrd` echoed there...

Comment: So you want to echo, or create a label? I will update my answer

Comment: im not sure what the write wording is but i think create label is the right one :) i know u can do this without programming but then i will never advance anywhere

Comment: thank you, ill start off with this!

Comment: if this isnt the place to ask for questions like this then what is?

Answer (score 2):

Please Check this http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Main_Page . It is suitable for every beginner, U can find as ur choice ios 5, ios 6, also on objective c with easy Example.

See my answer here to print on Screen by adding label. [Adding Label on Application Window from app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510835/adding-label-on-application-window-from-app-delegate/13511015#13511015)

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable over the implementation tag in your .m file. like, 
NSString *str=@"Hello";
Drag a UILabel in the .xib file and make a property of it in the .h file.

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *label;

Attach the UILabel to the property. Then in ViewdidLoad method of .m file asssign the variable to property, like

label.text=str;

That's all

Comment: viewcontrol or appdelegate files?

Comment: ok, thanks for your help! do you know any sites on which its ok to ask questions like this?

Comment: nope, i guess this site is the best.

Comment: haha, well they gave me a -2... not soo sure... if it is the best then how would I follow trapper's method and add a UIButton, it says there is no such thing as button.text = @"hi";

Comment: use button.title instead. button does not have any property as text.

Comment: um it says no such property as title...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20095/discussion-between-tihomfreak-and-muqman)